# Finding all possible sequences in a string

Tags: python

I have a string of dots and dashes (. or -) but some of them have been corrupted and replaced with x, I need to find the right sequence which appears in a different file.

To that end I thought of just replacing all X's to either dot or dash, and then try to find the sequence in the external file out of all of the options, but my code complexity is too bad for such a thing so the code never finish to run.

Someone can suggest a better alternative?

Here is my code for solving the problem:

```
encrypted_string = "x.xx...x.xxx..-xx-.xxxx.-.-xxx.-.x..x.xxxx..x.xxx.-.-.xx-.-xxx..-.xx.x.x.--x.xxx"
options = []
symbols = ['.','-']
index = 0
def getAllXOptions(string,index):
    if(index == len(string)):
        options.append(string)
        return 0
    
    if(string[index] == 'x'):
        string1 = string[:index] + '.' + string[index+1:]
        string2 = string[:index] + '-' + string[index+1:]
        getAllXOptions(string1, index+1)
        getAllXOptions(string2, index+1)
    
    else:
        getAllXOptions(string, index+1)
        
getAllXOptions(encrypted_string, index)
print(options)
```

Comment: Hello, what are the rules to determine whether 'x' should be '.' or '-'? As far as I can see, you calculate both options, you might have quite a lot of possible results

Comment: It's not clear how you will know what the correct replacement for any given `x` is. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "the right sequence which appears in a different file"? You should probably show us what's in the other file.

Comment: There are no rules.... I can tell you that it's suppose to represent a morse code without the spaces and my external file is also a morse code. But it an be either one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn your string into a regex and search in your file:

```
encrypted_string = "x.xx...x.xxx..-xx-.xxxx.-.-xxx.-.x..x.xxxx..x.xxx.-.-.xx-.-xxx..-.xx.x.x.--x.xxx"
regex = encrypted_string.replace('x', '[.-]').replace('.', r'\.')

with open('filename.txt') as f:
    secret = re.findall(regex, f.read())

secret
```

Comment: I think you want to replace the order of those `replace`s...

Comment: No, why? Or else I would need to escape the dot in the `[.-]`

Comment: Well it doesn't *really* matter. The `.` inside a character group is already literal. But it can also be escaped so it doesn't really matter...

Comment: Thanks I didn't get to check your answer but I'm sure its good. The first answer is working :)

Comment: @mashtock great! so, what was the secret message? ;)

Comment: @mozway :) I wish I could tell you. I am doing a session of programming riddles which are really hard and I still didn't manage to decode the morse code even after your help. If you'd like, I'll gladly try to get some assistant by sending you the full riddle privately .

Comment: @mozway The only reason I can't post here the full riddle is that the admins would get mad at me and I'll get tons of dislikes for posting riddles and not a clear question.

Answer (score 2):

How about regex, for example

```
import re
encrypted_string = "x.xx...x.xxx..-xx-.xxxx.-.-xxx.-.x..x.xxxx..x.xxx.-.-.xx-.-xxx..-.xx.x.x.--x.xxx"
possible_message = encrypted_string.replace('x', '[.-]')
m = re.search(possible_message, message)
possible_message = m.group(0)
```

Comment: `.` is a special character in regexes, this would match anything here ;)

Comment: Hmm looks nice, if I understand correctly it would find from message the right combination? I'll try it out.

Comment: But the dots from the `encrypted_string` are still not escaped so theoretically it could match something like `-a..bdc` and so on

Comment: Sorry, somehow at first I thought it worked but then I saw for some reason I got the wrong possible message. The other answer worked though

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the possible ways to write two elements, `.`and `-` repeated by the amount of `x`. Using `itertools.product` you can find such combinations.

In numbers: `2**n_x`, in your case `n_x = 39` -> `549755813888`-combinations.

```
# encrypted_string = "..-.xx.x.x.--x" # good for testing

encrypted_string = "x.xx...x.xxx..-xx-.xxxx.-.-xxx.-.x..x.xxxx..x.xxx.-.-.xx-.-xxx..-.xx.x.x.--x.xxx"


encrypted_string_formatted = encrypted_string.replace('x', '{}')

p = it.product('.-', repeat=encrypted_string.count('x'))

for i, c in enumerate(p):
    print(f'[{i+1}]', encrypted_string_formatted.format(*c))
```

Output (of the first 10 only)

```
[1] ..............-..-......-.-....-..................-.-...-.-.....-........--.....
[2] ..............-..-......-.-....-..................-.-...-.-.....-........--....-
[3] ..............-..-......-.-....-..................-.-...-.-.....-........--...-.
[4] ..............-..-......-.-....-..................-.-...-.-.....-........--...--
[5] ..............-..-......-.-....-..................-.-...-.-.....-........--..-..
[6] ..............-..-......-.-....-..................-.-...-.-.....-........--..-.-
[7] ..............-..-......-.-....-..................-.-...-.-.....-........--..--.
[8] ..............-..-......-.-....-..................-.-...-.-.....-........--..---
[9] ..............-..-......-.-....-..................-.-...-.-.....-........---....
[10] ..............-..-......-.-....-..................-.-...-.-.....-........---...-
```

Comment: I get confused by the title, my bad! I constructed all possible sequences... still an alternative... a bit time consuming

Comment: What you did is exactly what I originally wanted!

Comment: ahahaha... but forget about it... I let it run on my laptop for more than 5' (without printing) and than I killed it! The other solutions are more handy

Comment: Yeap, I actually knew to calculated as well how many combinations are there and figured I had no chance. Thats why I game them the answer XD. But Really thanks anyway!